# Accepting an offer to extend my notice period from my employer who let me go after probation?

Tags: notice-period, probation

After failing to pass a 3-month probation, I was asked to extend my notice period for one month. I believe it's because they haven't found a replacement and my position really is kind of important which is why they hired me in the first place even though it seemed from the beginning that we are not a good fit. In fact, they initially told me that my application was unsuccessful, and I was fine with that. A few days later, I got a call from them asking if I'm still interested. In need of a job, I said yes. They then gave me another exam which I passed, so they hired me. Having worked for this company for 5 months (my initial probation was delayed for a month), I can totally see where some of their hiring problems lie. And now I’m being asked to extend my notice period.

Since I’m an expat who needs to keep a visa and work permit to legitimize my stay in this city that I now call my second home, I realize that the most reasonable thing to do is say yes. On the other hand, part of me wants to say no. I’m grateful to them for taking a chance on me, but I wasn’t happy with how my former manager (who has just resigned) made it seem like I’ve somehow deceived her/them into thinking that I misrepresented myself to be hired, which is how we got to this point where they think I’m not suitable for their needs. I did not deceive them, and as much as I’d like to get into the meat of that probation review, the more pressing concern for me right now is, does it make sense to accept the offer to extend?

I have other options already lined up but the hiring process in these other companies will take several weeks. The obvious choice is to say yes, but I’m torn.

Comment: I've taken out the "what should I do" aspect of your question, as this is explicitly off topic.  However, the question can be generalised as to why is might be a good idea (or not).

Comment: What is local norm for gap between offer and hire date?  Also what was your given date of availability for these other companies?

Answer (score 8):

If you have something else firm to go to or you can afford to be out of work for an indeterminate length of time then reject it.  If you don't, then as long as you are going to be paid for your time you may as well accept it.

A number of reasons:

- Visas as you point out in your question
- Financial considerations - income is always a good thing
- It increases the length of time on the job on your CV, and reduces (a little) any possible inference of job hopping
- There is a possibility that they may yet rescind the rejection of probation, if you are willing to take on a role after this situation

The other opportunities you have, unless firmed up, will just have to deal with you having to give notice in your current role if something comes up with a start date before you end.  Alternatively you can negotiate a new start date.

Finally, given you have already been told you are leaving, the fact that you are actively seeking new employment should come as no surprise to your current employer.  Nor should it be a surprise if you give notice prior to the end of the agreed month if you secure another position.

Of course, if you feel too badly burned to stay, then that is your prerogative.  But do consider the above benefits in accepting the offer.

Comment: Also, he can negotiate for a letter of recommendation for the next employer.  That NEVER hurts.  If they want him to stay for that month or so, they're write it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've considered staying for the above reasons, but I still wasn't convinced that it was worth the embarrassment and the awkwardness of staying and working with managers who find my work unsatisfactory. It's not an easy decision to make but ultimately, I guess, I have to be practical. Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: @PJExpat Remember your work is not that unsatisfactory - they prefer continuing to pay you to do it to not having it done. It is not as good as the hypothetical worker they have not yet been able to hire.